# How to create custom calendar view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-calendar

I followed some tutorials and i tried some examples. Even I'm not get the proper ways to implement the `Custom Calendar` View. I followed the tutorial from [LINK](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html) and i got the error of `USER Permission Calendar READ Or WRITE`, in `Manifest file`.

After added the Calendar view permission in manifest file even though error is same. i am working in Android studio please guid me !!!

Comment: did you tried rebuilding your project

Comment: The following link will help http://javatechig.com/android/custom-calendar-view-library-in-android

Comment: Thanks Nilanchala :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

If above is giving the error then your code must be wrong

Comment: i imported downloaded project in android studio,even i get same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve by using custom calendar view but I suggest that you take a look at this [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/README.md)

It leverages all the work for you, display the same calendar across all devices and versions and it's neat and beautiful with Material design ;)